# ViewController doesn't receive NSNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I'm getting frustrated with NSNotification. Somehow my view controller can not receive callback . I've browsed on the internet but not found any solution for that. Here is my code

SideBarViewController.h

```
- (void)postNotificationWithString:(NSString *)deviceLocation {

    NSString *notificationName = @"LocationDetectedNotification";

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:deviceLocation forKey:@"MyLocation"];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:notificationName object:nil userInfo:dict];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

if (currentLocation != nil) {
  lon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
  lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
  [self postNotificationWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", lat, lon]];

}
// Save battery consumption
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

TestViewController.h

```
@implementation TestViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization


}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(useNotificationWithString:) name:@"LocationDetectedNotification" object:nil];

{
- (void)useNotificationWithString:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"Location Retrieved");
    NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];
    self.location = [dict valueForKey:@"MyLocation"];

}
```

When I click on `TestViewController`, nothing happened. I used `storyboard` for creating view controllers.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you getting any error wile run time or nothing happens?

Comment: @AnuragSoni, I got no error, just nothing happens. I tested with NSLog, the message showed up in the console, not with the data in callback method

Comment: Where do you call postNotificationWIthString?

Comment: It's in this method `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations `. I use this to notify the location get updated

Comment: Can u directly use @"LocationDetectedNotification" while posting the notification instead of notificationName variable, its just a guess..not sure about it...just try it..

Comment: Which data can you log instead in the callback?

Comment: put a break point in useNotificationWithString: and inspect the variable "dict".  What does it contain?

Comment: @Bek, the point is method `useNotificationWithString` is not fired when `TestViewController` loaded. I did put a break point but nothing happened

Comment: @Xman, nothing happened bro

Comment: try to debug whether your execution of prgramme goes into if(currentLocation != nil) or not

Comment: @Vik, I put `NSLog(@"blah blah")` in `viewDidLoad` method, it showed everytime I click on `TestViewController`

Comment: Are you sure `CLLocationManager` is running?

Comment: Are you sure that TestViewController "exists" when the notification fires? Maybe it was already unloaded? Is it visible at the time the notification fires.  If you put a break point in postNotificationWithString:, does that get hit?

Comment: @AnuragSoni, the code worked fine `Found placemarks: (
    "Apple Store, San Francisco, Apple Store, San Francisco, 1800 Ellis St, San Francisco, CA  94115-4004, United States @ <+37.78584540,-122.40651750> `

Comment: @Bek, yeah, i got `postNotificationWithString` hit

Comment: You are 100% sure that TestViewController exists when a notification is fired? I mean, does `postNotificationWithString` get executed AFTER your TestViewController's `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @micantox, I'm not sure about that. Could you confirm that? I have a `SideBarViewController` and `TestViewController` is showed up after I click on a cell of `SideBarViewController`. I'm using SWRevealViewController library.`

Comment: Ok, let's look at it from a different angle: where do you call `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]`?

Comment: @micantox, in `SideBarViewController viewDidLoad` method

Comment: Can you post the code where you are instantiating TestViewController?  as in a [[TestViewController alloc] init....] kind of thing.

Comment: @Bek, i just updated, pls look at my post, I created a tableviewcontroller on `storyboard` and have `TestViewController` as a `custom class`

Comment: sorry, that's not what I'm looking for.  I want to know *where in SideViewController* you instantiate TestViewController because I suspect that it does not exist yet when you post your notification, therefore it cannot receive the notification.

Comment: oh, actually, I use a segue from a table view cell of `SideBarViewController` to `TestViewController`. Everytime I click on that cell, it move to `TestViewController`.

Comment: @micantox, omg, your answer come to rescue. You're right. I just double check that by comment out [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]

Comment: Tks guys, specially Bek and micantox for helping me out. Wish you the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem here is that you do `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` in the `viewDidLoad` method of your first view controller, then you do `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]` in the `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations` method.

My guess is that you receive the location and you stop the location manager, *before* you instantiate your `TestViewController`, which means that no observer was registered yet.